# react add class to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newb here. Attempting to set className on (dynamically created but static in example) child element(s). Click on child and parent receives event and changes child's styles accordingly. Trivial in vanilla.js but want to know the "react way".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sel : "none"};
        this.handleChildClick = this.handleChildClick.bind(this);
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
            {this.state.sel}
            <div>
                <ChildClass onClick={this.handleChildClick}/>
            </div>      
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleChildClick = (event) => {
    // console.log(event);
    // want to change background color of child by adding className
    this.setState({
        sel : event.target.innerHTML
    })  
  }
}
class ChildClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.props.onClick}>
                div or li or button
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

-------- EDIT ----

### Simple javascript version - looking for pure react way

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
.selected {
    background-color: #09f;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="d_1" class='clk'>one</div>
<div id="d_2" class='clk'>two</div>
<div id="d_3" class='clk'>three</div>

<script>
let ele = document.querySelectorAll('.clk');
ele.forEach(function(e,v,t) {
    e.onclick = setThis;
});
var sel = '';
function setThis(e) {
    if(sel.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById(sel).classList.remove('selected');
    }
    document.getElementById(e.target.id).classList.add('selected');
    sel = e.target.id;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the classname, `sel` here I think, to your child component? Am I missing something?

Comment: Need to pass className from parent on click not init. The 'sel' in the parent state was just to make sure I was passing event.target

Comment: You can't specify something like that I think, I mean passing the props just after the click event. But, you can pass a prop with a null value, then change it according to your click handler. Is this ok for you? Also, what will specify the class name here? Target's `innerHTML` as in your example?

Comment: Can but don't want to set the class "locally". I want to reference the dom node dynamically from the parent. Say a bunch of generated divs but only one can be red. So color this and uncolor previous. Trivial in javascript but curious about "pure" react.

Comment: Then, explain this in your question a little bit more :) I can write what you want here with a couple of different ways probably as a rookie but all of them includes my imagination. How do we get class names, how do we keep which element will use this class name, etc? For example, I can keep a state property and specify the element here (somehow) and pass this value to the child component. According to this value, I can specify the class in the elements. But, this wouldn't suit you again maybe. So, try to give all the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you want exactly, but here is a very simple example.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { childClass: "" };

  handleChildClick = e =>
    this.setState( {
      childClass: e.target.innerHTML,
    } );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChildClass
          childClass={this.state.childClass}
          onClick={this.handleChildClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ChildClass = props => (
  <div onClick={props.onClick} className={props.childClass}>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>yellow</li>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Update after comments**

Here is the example according to your pure JS code if I understand it right :) I'm using a hardcoded `div` list here as you can see. This is because I don't know how will you generate your divs. Maybe you will get them from an array. If this is so this code will be much more practical. Map through the array and create the divs according to their id's and so on. But, here is the hardcoded version.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: "" };

  handleChildClick = e => this.setState( { selected: e.target.id } );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChildClass
          selected={this.state.selected}
          onClick={this.handleChildClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const ChildClass = props => (
  <div>
    <div
      id="d_1"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={props.selected === "d_1" ? "clk" : ""}
    >
      one
    </div>
    <div
      id="d_2"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={props.selected === "d_2" ? "clk" : ""}
    >
      two
    </div>
    <div
      id="d_3"
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={props.selected === "d_3" ? "clk" : ""}
    >
      three
    </div>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById( "root" ) );
```

```css
.clk {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Here is the map version of how you can generate divs maybe.

```
const ChildClass = ( props ) => {
  const divs = [
    { id: "d_1", text: "one" },
    { id: "d_2", text: "two" },
    { id: "d_3", text: "three" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      {divs.map( el => (
        <div
          key={el.id}
          onClick={props.onClick}
          id={el.id}
          className={props.selected === el.id ? "clk" : ""}
        >
          {el.text}
        </div>
      ) )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Interesting thanks. You're binding(? probably wrong word) the child class to the parent on init. I'll explore this. I'm just doing a simple select style menu where only one div / td / li ... can be selected at a time, so on selecting one the previously selected needs to be unselected (and color changed back).

Comment: You are welcome. Not binding (as the word) but render a child component here and passing a state value and a callback handler. As I tried to explain in my other comment if you can give some more detail in your question people probably can give you better suggestions.

Comment: By the way, here you are ( also I am :) ) using event bubbling (the right word I hope). We are using the callback in the main div, so when we click a `li` element it goes all the way up and hit the handler. This suits for this example but you want to set your callback handler separately in each element probably. You will use a `map` to generate those elements, set all the props there. One of them will be the callback handler. There are too many ways of doing this. So again, more details :)

Comment: Hey thanks for your interest in this. Simplest way to describe is quick js example. ... and stack software isn't letting me embed(?) hmmm. I'm going to edit original question and see if that works.

Comment: @openquestions, you are welcome. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you! I'm not a big fan of react but I want to get my head around the react way. Mapping the array of objects is a cool take as well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ChildClass
onClick={this.handleChildClick}
className={this.state.sel}
/>
```

And you have to add `className={this.props.className}` to your `div` in `ChildClass`